# Grails deployment error

Tags: grails, deployment

I've manage to deploy my Grails app on my local pc on Tomcat and database is on MySql server but I cant manage to do it on remote server in the same enviroment.
This is the begining of stacktrace:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the same JVM version on the server as you are using on your local pc OR use a higher version on the server. Typically, that should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You're compiling and running with different JVM versions.

The JDK version on your computer should be the same that is installed on the remote server.